# Kendo ui autocomplete events

Tags: events, asp.net-mvc-4, keypress, kendo-autocomplete

I am working on ASP.NET MVC4 application.And i am using Kendo MVC controls inside my views/partial views.

> > And i am using Kendo AutoComplete control.My problem is i am not getting the way to set kendo autocomplete controls KeyPress event.

Is anyone know how can we set the keypress event for kendo autocomplete?

This the code for events:-

.Events(e => e.Select("select").Change("change"))

In which i want to use keypress event also.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no way to do this using the Events helper method.

However you can do this :

```
Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m => m.PropertyName)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { onkeypress="keypress" })
```